# UML to Java tool?

Tags: java, uml, code-generation

I wonder is there any tool (preferably free) that can generate Java source code from UML diagrams?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides NetBeans, I imagine the following will do the job :

- [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/features.html)
- Jude Community Edition (sorry, it's now called [Astah Community](http://astah.change-vision.com/en/product/astah-community.html))
- [Omondo](http://www.ejb3.org/index.html), without a doubt

Answer (score 4):

Try NetBeans, [Here is youtube demonstrating the process](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoHkCYW72Ew)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [JUDE](http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/index.html)

Comment: See my link, Jude has now become Astah.

Comment: @Riduidel: The link he provided is also suggesting the same, BTW. :)

Comment: Yes, but as Jude markets itself as becoming Astah, i think it should be emphazied here.

Answer (score 2):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/), and it's more commercial version, [PoseidonUML](http://www.gentleware.com/), have this option.

Also, JetBrain's [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) have a UML editor that can add fields and methods.

Comment: It's important to note that IntelliJ does not support UML diagrams in its community edition, only its paid ultimate edition.

Comment: I just hope he's sanitzing his UML Diagrams

Answer (score 2):

Code generation tools are often target agnostic. It is usually a matter of whether  generation templates or cartridges exist for the intended target platform.

[Acceleo](http://acceleo.org) is Eclipse-based and has a plug-in for UML2-to-Java generation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used BOUML myself, but my old project manager was fanatical about it, and he was telling me about how it supports UML->Java code generation (and reverse engineering). Might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

here is one more free for non-commercial use. may be learners can make use of this
http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp?edition=ce

Answer (score 0):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/)

> A solid UML 2.4.1 core coupled with an intuitive user interface and
>   efficient, highly scalable repository is the basis for one of the most
>   successful UML tools ever created. 300,000 users worldwide, a vigorous
>   user community, endorsements from major standards bodies, an
>   affordable price point, numerous accolades and a proven record of
>   delivering exceptional results.

Answer (score 0):

Star UML
you can download it frm here http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/download.php